# How to configurate nginx and uwsgi to redirect calls from path to subdomain?

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

i am running a flask app on uwsgi and nginx. They website serves two functions:

- `/admin`:for backend administration
- `/api`:for rest api

I want all api calls go through the subdomain:api.mysite.com.

It is runing very well if i call api like `www.mysite.com/api/v1/cities`.

what if i want to call the api this way, `api.mysite.com/v1/cities`?

How could i manage to do this?

Answer (score 5):

I managed to get it working by setting proxy_pass on nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/app.sock;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.mysite.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost/api/;  
    }
}
```

still thinking if it is the best solution and is there any overhead to the server?